# Travis CI Android build failed to detect file in Product Flavour directory

Tags: android, travis-ci

My Android project has two product flavour **FlavourOne** & **FlavourTwo** and  BuildType **Debug** & **Release**.

My project src directory has

1. main
2. FlavourOneDebug
3. FlavourOneRelease
4. FlavourTwoDebug
5. FlavourTwoRelease

**xxx.xxx.test.constant.FlavourConstant** is placed in FlavourOneDebug, FlavourOneRelease, FlavourTwoDebug, FlavourTwoRelease and not in main directory

**xxx.xxx.test.MainActivity** which is placed in main directory imports **FlavourConstant**

here is my travis.yml

```
language: android
sudo: required
jdk: oraclejdk8

android:
  components:

  # The BuildTools version used by your project
  - build-tools-26.0.2

  # The SDK version used to compile your project
  - android-26

  # Additional components
  - extra-google-google_play_services
  - extra-google-m2repository
  - extra-android-m2repository

  before_cache:
  - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -fr $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/

  cache:
    directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
    - $HOME/.android/build-cache

    before_install:
    - mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
    - echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
    - echo -e "\n84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"

script:
  - ./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

Travis CI failed to reference FlavourConstant from product flavour directory.

[image]

Reference to Travis failed job https://travis-ci.org/KarthikUCH/MokaTest/jobs/527169383

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to solve the issue, which is actually caused by the flavour source set directory naming.

The Gradle task in Travis expects the flavour directory to be CaseSensitive.

Changed the directory naming form `flavoruonedebug` to `flavoruoneDebug` solved the issue